# Text Outlining Using WPF Shader

Tags: wpf, shader, outline, formatted-text

I tried to google it out, but is there any sample Shader effect which I could use to produce an outlined FormattedText. I was able to get the outline by using BuildGeometry(), but the performance is very poor!

[image: outlined Text]

PS: Since I'm new to this and still learning, it would be helpful if anyone can suggest whether it would be even possible or not.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easy option I whipped up, but not sure if it's exactly what you want.  Just use an `OuterGlowBitmapEffect`.

You can paste my example straight into Kaxaml to see what it looks like:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid Background="Black">  
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Text" Foreground="White">
      <TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
        <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Orange" GlowSize="6" />
      </TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
    </TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image]

Comment: Some users report this DOES NOT work on .NET 4 because BitmapEffect was deprecated.... it keeps on working for me tho :p

Comment: Thanks for giving me the heads up.  I personally love the effect but was using it on .NET 3.5.  I just upgraded to .NET 4.0 last week.  :)  I hope it's been replaced by something just as easy!

Comment: GlowEffect not equivalent to Outline. What I need is an Outline, without using BuildGeometry().